# Крестики-нолики на React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, инспекция-кода

Доброе утро, сограждане. Оцените мой код (React) по 10-бальной шкале, и укажите на явные ошибки, затупы, и прочее...)

Буду очень благодарен!

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import {gameBlock} from './api'
import {calculateWinner} from './checkWin'

class TicTac extends Component {

constructor (props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
        gameBlock,
        current: 0
    }
}

addCymeriad = (index) => {

    let gameBlock = this.state.gameBlock
    let current = this.state.current

    if (calculateWinner(gameBlock) === 'X' ) return
    if (calculateWinner(gameBlock) === '0' ) return

    if (gameBlock[index] === 'X') return
    if (gameBlock[index] === '0') return



    if (current % 2 === 0) {
        gameBlock[index] = 'X'
    } else {
        gameBlock[index] = '0'
    }

    this.setState({gameBlock: gameBlock, current: this.state.current + 1})
    calculateWinner(gameBlock)
}

nextPlayer = () => {
    if (this.state.current % 2 === 0) {
        return 'X'
    } else {
        return '0'
    }
}

startGame = () => {

    let gameBlock = this.state.gameBlock

    for (let i = 0; i < gameBlock.length; i++) {
        gameBlock[i] = ''
        this.setState({gameBlock: this.state.gameBlock, current: 0})
    }
}


render() {
    const gameBlockList = this.state.gameBlock.map((item, index) => {
        return <div onClick={this.addCymeriad.bind(null, index)} key={index} className='game__block'>{item}</div>
    })

    const winner = calculateWinner(gameBlock)

    const player = this.nextPlayer()

  return (
    <div>
        <div className="game">
            {gameBlockList}
            <p className='win'>Победитель: {winner}</p>
            <input onClick={this.startGame} value='Начать заново' type="button" className="start__game"/>
        </div>
        <div className="nextPlayer">
            Следующий игрок: {player}
        </div>
    </div>
  );
}
}

export default TicTac;
```

*И функция calculateWinner*

```
export function calculateWinner(squares) {
const lines = [
 [0, 1, 2],
 [3, 4, 5],
 [6, 7, 8],
 [0, 3, 6],
 [1, 4, 7],
 [2, 5, 8],
 [0, 4, 8],
 [2, 4, 6]
]

for (let i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
const [a, b, c] = lines[i]
if (
  squares[a] &&
  squares[a] === squares[b] &&
  squares[a] === squares[c]
) {
  return squares[a]
}
}

return null
}
```

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что это неподходящее место для кодревью

Comment: Почему неподходящее место? Я поискал на сайте подобные вопросы, и, знаете, нашел.

Comment: оценка кода - не несет пользы для сообщества. Если у вас есть вопросы по тому, как конкретную часть кода оптимизировать скажем - велком, а так это просто переливание из пустого в порожнее.

Comment: Я также попросил указать на явные ошибки в коде, которые помогут начинающим React разработчикам их не повторять.

Comment: @MedvedevDev, тогда почему есть метка инспекция-кода? Она же:  code-review, ревью-кода, код-ревью и ревью

Comment: Есть специальный сайт в системе stackexchange: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @gil9red, потому что в ру мете нет соответствующего ресурса, по этому для таких вопросов была выделена метка. Однако её наличие не означает, что стоит кидать на ревью любой кусок кода и просить его проинспектить. Это мое личное мнение, но ревью "начинающих разработчиков" это довольно сомнительный "контент" (да, в описании причины закрытия я слишком обобщил, каюсь). Под какую категорию метки можно подписать данный топик? "Лучшие практики и использование паттернов"? Сомневаюсь. Остальные совсем мимо.

Comment: @MedvedevDev вопросы-ревью разрешены: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1761/. Если вы считаете,  что этот вопрос не попадает под категорию разрешенных - пожалуйста, подскажите топикастеру,  что именно нужно добавить или уточнить.

Comment: CC @Komdosh ^^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Из того, что сразу бросается в глаза:

1) В функции `startGame` творится ад.

- Создаем `let gameBlock = this.state.gameBlock`, и `gameBlock` - не
  массив, а ссылка на массив. И когда мы **в него записываем значение**
  `gameBlock[i] = ''`, то **меняем значение в this.state** (руками и ногами в стейт лучше не лазить).
- Делать `setState()` на каждую итерацию цикла - не лучшее решение.

Можно сделать так(`[].map()` - возвращает новый массив, а не изменяет используемый):

```
this.setState({gameBlock: this.state.gameBlock.map(block => ''), current: 0})
```

2) Использовать диструктуризацию:

```
let gameBlock = this.state.gameBlock
let current = this.state.current
```

Поменять на

```
let {gameBlock, current} = this.state
```

3) Использовать es6 синтаксис для указания свойств объекта

```
this.setState({gameBlock: gameBlock})
```

На

```
this.setState({gameBlock})
```

4) Arrow function

```
(item, index) => { return <div> ... </div>}
```

Тоже самое что и

```
(item, index) => <div> ... </div>
```

5) Если функция `calculateWinner` будет выполняться 4-5 секунды, сколько потеряете на такой проверки времени?

```
   if (calculateWinner(gameBlock) === 'X' ) return
   if (calculateWinner(gameBlock) === '0' ) return
```

6) Использовать prettier, linter что бы код был в одном стиле, индентации

```
className="game"
className='win'
```